# weird javascript/jquery behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don’t self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

I had this bit of javascript code inside a <head> element.

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#welcome").addClass("centered");
        $("#created").addClass("centered");
    });
</script>
```

Which refused to work until I used an explicit end script element:

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Why is there a difference?

EDIT: the entire header was:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueprint/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
    <!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" /><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueprint/src/typography.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" />

    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#welcome").addClass("centered");
            $("#created").addClass("centered");
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

I don't understand why the script element needs an explicit end element but the link element doesnt.

Comment: Refused to work in which browser?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Comment: @Chris Missal: I'm testing with IE 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you always need to end script elements like that. It doesn't support the XHTML format of ' />' to end the tag.

Comment: I've noticed this was the case, and now close all js-related tags this way, but is there any particular reason? I'm aware it's probably a duplicate question, but that's why this is just a comment.

Comment: I don't know exactly, but my guess would be it's due to compatibility. Quirksmode has some info : http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/06/MSIE_script_tag_failure_in_valid_xhtml.html

Comment: Technically the `/>` format is valid in XHTML, but never in HTML—well, it actually has an obscure, rarely-implemented meaning. And even if you think you’re writing XHTML, odds are it’s being served as `text/html` and so the browser is treating it as HTML. The fact that tags like `<br />` work (the HTML version is just `<br>` with no closing tag) is only because HTML parsers are forgiving.

Comment: If an element has an empty content model then the XML empty-element syntax is acceptable. If an element does *not* have an empty content model, the XML syntax is not acceptable. Check the HTML 4.01 or XHTML 1.0 DTDs for details of which elements have an empty content model.

Answer (score 2):

What is the doctype of your document? Technically minimized tags like your first example are an XML-only thing. In most cases HTML allow them, but the correct HTML is your second example.

Answer (score 1):

Certain elements like `script` and `iframe` dont work correctly in all browsers unless you have a closing tag, even if there is no content inside. While I agree that this is stupid, its just one more of those inconsistencies that web developers need to be aware of.

I would imagine that once browser vendors implement *actual* XHTML (so we can send XHMTL as application/xhtml+xml not text/html) that at that point they would also fix inconsistencies like this. Or maybe I'm just an optimist.

Comment: Good luck with that, with HTML5 out, XHTML will most likely NEVER reach that point.

Comment: AFAIK they've only suspended work on XHTML2 until HTML5 is done, though I sympathize with your pessimism :)